# .net Razor code block within an inline css declaration

Tags: c#, .net, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

@homePartnership.Batsman1Runs is the dynamic value from an api and px is static, if it runs next to each other, it breaks as @homePartnership.Batsman1Runspx isnt a valid field and if there is a space, html wont follow the width, below is what I currently have, it does not work.

```
<div class="left-bar" style="width:@homePartnership.Batsman1Runs{<text>px</text>}"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround the dynamic part with parentheses (the `@( ... )` construct):

```
<div class="left-bar" style="width:@(homePartnership.Batsman1Runs)px"></div>
```

Note that Razor parses on whitespace, so this is valid Razor syntax: "width: @homePartnership.Batsman1Runs px".  But of course, that produces "width: 5 px", which isn't quite valid CSS.  However, as above, you can always add the parentheses to delineate a code block.

For reference, inline Razor Syntax:

- [A very good C# summary](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/153/Inline-Razor-Syntax-Overview)
- [Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx)